# Trying to Create a Scatterplot in R with Labels and Color Legend

Tags: r, plot, scatter

With that data below, I need to have a scatterplot with each item in the "Name" column labeling their corresponding XY plot. The Goal Column would represent group coloring, as indicated by the legend. I'm new at R and have gotten only as far as plotting X and Y.

```
X    Y  Name    Goal                Color   
0.582   30  FS1Br1  Acummulation        BLUE    
0.612   33  FS1Br2  Acummulation        BLUE    
0.725   28  FS1Br3  Acummulation        BLUE    
0.532   27  FS1Br4  Acummulation        BLUE    
0.615   30  FS1Br5  Acummulation        BLUE    
0.562   23  FS2Br1  Processing          GREEN   
0.653   22  FS2Br2  Processing          GREEN   
0.66    25  FS2Br3  Processing          GREEN   
0.595   21  FS2Br4  Processing          GREEN   
0.665   30  FS2Br5  Processing          GREEN   
0.581   26  FS2Br6  Processing          GREEN   
0.684   32  FS2Br7  Processing          GREEN   
0.62    26  FS3Br1  Data Analysis       YELLOW  
0.733   27  FS3Br2  Data Analysis       YELLOW  
0.59    23  FS3Br3  Data Analysis       YELLOW  
0.582   22  FS3Br4  Data Analysis       YELLOW  
0.595   20  FS3Br5  Data Analysis       YELLOW  
0.639   18  FS3Br6  Data Analysis       YELLOW  
0.625   22  FS3Br7  Data Analysis       YELLOW  
0.585   33  FS4Br1  Value Add Insights  RED 
0.61    24  FS4Br10 Value Add Insights  RED 
0.649   26  FS4Br2  Value Add Insights  RED 
0.576   26  FS4Br3  Value Add Insights  RED 
0.596   31  FS4Br4  Value Add Insights  RED 
0.5     32  FS4Br5  Value Add Insights  RED 
0.673   24  FS4Br6  Value Add Insights  RED 
0.696   21  FS4Br7  Value Add Insights  RED 
0.681   28  FS4Br8  Value Add Insights  RED 
0.571   28  FS4Br9  Value Add Insights  RED
```

Here's the code I've tried to use so far:

```
plot(data$X,
     data$Y,
     pch=1,
     cex=1.0,
     bg="black",
     col="black",
     xlab="Correlation Coefficient",
     ylab="Top-Box %",
     main="Google")
```

Comment: Can you post the R code that you have so far?

Comment: plot(data$X,data$Y, pch=1, cex=1.0, bg="black", col="black", xlab="Correlation Coefficient", ylab="Top-Box %", main="Google")

Comment: It would help if you created a minimal working example for us to work on. If you included a `data.frame()` command that we could use to create your dataset, along with what you were doing in the question itself (you can edit it to include your comment) it would make it a lot easier to answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `df` is your data set, you can try `ggplot2` package

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = X, y = Y,  label = Name)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("blue", "green", "yellow", "red")) +
  geom_text(aes(color = Goal), hjust=1.1, vjust=1.1, size = 5) +
  labs(title = "Google", x = "Correlation Coefficient", y = "Top-Box %")
```

[image]

A bit different version where the points are the same color as names

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = X, y = Y, color = Goal)) + 
  geom_point() + scale_colour_manual(values = c("blue", "green", "yellow", "red")) +
  geom_text(aes(label = Name), hjust=1.1, vjust=1.1, size = 5) +
  labs(title = "Google", x = "Correlation Coefficient", y = "Top-Box %")
```

[image]

Third version where the labels are black

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = X, y = Y,  color = Goal)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("blue", "green", "yellow", "red")) +
  geom_text(aes(label = Name), color = "black", hjust=1.1, vjust=1.1, size = 5) +
  labs(title = "Google", x = "Correlation Coefficient", y = "Top-Box %")
```

[image]

Comment: @beginneR, I'm not sure bout the shorter code, but the plot is indeed looks nicer and the legend is not an issue

Comment: any way to get the text below or next to the plot? Im taking out the first three characters anyway (they correspond to the colors)

Comment: @user3638007 Not sure what you mean

Comment: oh wait I did not see the next update... this is so nice, thank you so much, lastly, is there a way to adjust font size and color (color for each individual category, they have to correspond to a workbook)

Comment: See update above. added `scale_colour_manual(values = c("blue", "green", "yellow", "red"))` for manually filling colors and `size = 5` in the `geom_text`. You can adjust both size and colors as you wish

Comment: Thank you so much, pretty much exactly what I needed. I want to change the labels to black, and the plots to corresponding colors. I can't find where that element is missing

Comment: See edit above. If you want to inlarge the points size you can change to `geom_point(size = 5)` or whatever size you want

Comment: YES, so perfect, I've been adjusting the angle to see if I could get some of the words to not overlap, overlapping isn't something that can be adjusted I'm assuming

Comment: add `, position = "jitter"` into `geom_text()`

Comment: Take out `position = "jitter"` out of the `aes`. it should be `geom_text(aes(label = Name), color = "black", hjust=1.1, vjust=1.1, size = 5, position = "jitter")`

Comment: Also, if this the correct answer, please select it as by checking it, thank you

Comment: I am so sorry, but my last problem is, the Goal Legend was automatically placed in alphabetical order, when it should be Accumulation, Processing, Data Analysis, Value Add Insights (the order of the spread sheet)

Comment: Do `df$Goal <- factor(df$Goal, levels = c("Acummulation", "Processing", "Data Analysis", "Value Add Insights"))` and the run the plot again

Comment: > data$Goal <- factor(data$Goal, levels = c("Accumulation", "Processing", "Data Analysis", "Value Add Insights")
+ 
+ ggplot(data = data, aes(x = X, y = Y,  color = Goal)) + 
Error: unexpected symbol in:
"
ggplot"
>   geom_point(size=3) + 
+   scale_colour_manual(values = c("blue", "green", "yellow", "red")) +
+   geom_text(aes(label = Label), position = "jitter", color = "black", hjust=0.7, vjust=1.2, size = 2) 
Error in geom_point(size = 3) + scale_colour_manual(values = c("blue",  : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: I'm not sure why you are pasting it here, but don't run the like above and plot at the same line